# char does not contain a definition for 'CIP_ID'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to retrieve data (Description) from a record through the primary key (CIP_ID), however I keep getting an error CS1061 which has to do with `x.CIP_ID` but I don't understand why this error keeps popping up nor what I can do to fix it. I've tried using `.First`, `.Element` which also all give errors.

```
public ActionResult GetCIPDesc(int CIP_ID)
{
    CIP_Number temp = new CIP_Number();
    var desc = temp.Description.Where(x => x.CIP_ID == CIP_ID);
    ViewBag.CIPNumDesc = desc;
    return PartialView("CIPDescPartial");
}
```

> CS1061:
>            char does not contain a definition for 'CIP_ID' and no extension method 
>           'CIP_ID; accepting a first argument of type 'char' could be found (are you 
>            missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up working for me. I used a ViewModel to display `@Item.Text.`

```
public ActionResult GetCIPDesc(int CIP_ID)
    {
        CIP_Number temp = new CIP_Number();
        List<CIP_Number> desc = db.CIP_Numbers.Where(x => x.CIP_ID == CIP_ID).ToList();
        ViewBag.CIPNumDesc = new SelectList(desc, "CIP_ID", "Description");
        return PartialView("CIPDescPartial");
    }
```